# How to create dots and values on top of them on the Area chart using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

So I am trying to create a KPI tool for my team using Jupyter notebook, but I got stuck at creating dots and values on top of them on the Area chart.
Code:

```
df_all = pd.DataFrame(columns=['total_message_with_event','total_message','captured_ratio'], index = np.arange(5))
df_all.index = week_table
df_all.total_message = result[0]
df_all.total_message_with_event = result_with_event[0]
df_all.captured_ratio = ratio
df_graph = df_all[['total_message_with_event','total_message']]
df_graph = df_graph[::-1]
graph = df_graph.plot.area(title='Event Team Week-based Statistics', stacked = False)
box = graph.get_position()
graph.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width, box.height*0.9])
graph.legend(df_all[['total_message_with_event','total_message']], loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.728, 1.25))
graph.set_ylabel('Number of Messages')
graph.yaxis.set_tick_params(pad=2)
def millions(x, pos):
    'The two args are the value and tick position'
    return '%1.1fM' % (x*1e-6)
formatter = FuncFormatter(millions)
graph.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
df_all = df_all[::-1]
df_all
```

[Current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLqUI.png)

It should look like this with dots and values on top of them:
[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzsvK.png)

Comment: Please give us a sample of your `df_graph`so we have data to play with

Comment: Hi Julien, df_graph is a smaller dataframe of df_all which is visualized as this table http://www.clipular.com/c/6217248557760512.png?k=ztk3lSiZtIhY3Db4dSYRqtDenKs

Comment: Please look at other pandas questions to see how to include a sample of your data that one can import using pandas.read_clipboard().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some sample data to work with since you didn't provide any usable data:

```
np.random.seed(0)
df_graph = pd.DataFrame(data=np.transpose([np.random.rand(5)*1e7,np.random.rand(5)*1e6]),
                      columns=['total_message','total_message_with_event'],
                      index = ["Week {}".format(x) for x in range(40,45)])
```

Now let's create your chart by plotting both area and line chart on the same axes:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(16,9))

colors = ['#3366CC', '#DC3912']
colors_light = ['#C2D1F0', '#CAA4AE']
# Plot an area chart
df_graph.plot.area(stacked = False, color=colors_light, ax=ax, alpha=0.5)
# Plot a line chart with dot markers on the same chart
df_graph.plot(ax=ax, marker='o', color=colors, legend=False)

ax.set_title(label='Event Team Week-based Statistics', size=18)

#box = graph.get_position()
#ax.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width, box.height*0.9])
#ax.legend(df_all[['total_message_with_event','total_message']], loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.728, 1.25))

ax.set_ylabel('Number of Messages')
ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(pad=2)

def millions(x, pos):
    'The two args are the value and tick position'
    return '%1.1fM' % (x*1e-6)
formatter = mpl.ticker.FuncFormatter(millions)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

for i, label in enumerate(list(df_graph.index)):
    # Annotate the first
    score = df_graph.ix[label, 'total_message_with_event']
    ax.annotate("{:,.0f}".format(score), (i, score), va='bottom',ha='center')
    # Annotate the second
    score = df_graph.ix[label, 'total_message']
    ax.annotate("{:,.0f}".format(score), (i, score), va='bottom',ha='center')
```

[image: Resulting chart]

### Update / Side note

Here's a solution using plotly:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import cufflinks as cf
df_graph.iplot(kind='scatter', fill=True, symbol='dot', mode='lines+markers',
               title='Event Team Week-based Statistics',
               yTitle="Number of messages",
               colors = ['#3366CC', '#DC3912'])
```

This gives you an interactive graph directly in Jupyter notebook where on hover it displays the values:

[image]

You can test this graph online [here](https://plot.ly/~jmarrec/282/event-team-week-based-statistics/).